# Wrong session value when reading

Tags: php, session

I have got this strange problem. I wanted to make a page which uses a Username to identify which content should be displayed. It seems to work fine, except for one thing. The wrong value is read from the session on one specific page. I have checked the session value in my browser, but there the value seems to be correct. I'll show you the code:

this is my login function, using php:

```
<?php

//CONNECT TO DATABASE
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","MyPassword","MyDBName");
if($db->connect_errno){
die('connection error: ' . $db->connect_errno);
}

   //CHECK IF LOGIN DATA IS SUBMITTED AND IS CORRECT
if(isset($_POST['action'])){
switch($_POST['action']){
    case "login":
        $pw = $_POST['pw'];
        $loginUn = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['loginUn']);
        $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT `Password` FROM `accounts` WHERE `Username`='" .$loginUn. "'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0){
            $dbpw = $result->fetch_object();
            $VI = explode("-",$dbpw->Password);
            $dbpw = openssl_decrypt($VI[1],"blowfish","",0,$VI[0]);
            if($pw == $dbpw){
                $login = true;
                $_SESSION['login'] = true;
                $_SESSION['Username'] = $_POST['loginUn'];
                $un = $_POST['loginUn'];
            }
        }
        break;
    case "logout":
            $_SESSION['login'] = false;
            $_SESSION['Username'] = "";
        break;
}
}else{
    if(isset($_SESSION['login'])){
        $login = $_SESSION['login'];
        $un = $_SESSION['Username'];
    }
}

?>
```

it seems to work fine, since it works in the page it is used.
I have made some dummy accounts in the database, with these usernames: Admin and User.
Here is the code of the page it went wrong:

PHP:

```
//THIS IS NOT THE SAME PAGE AS THE PREVIOUS PHP CODE
$login = false;             //CHECK IF USER HAS LOGGED IN
$un = "";                   

if(isset($_SESSION['login'])){
$login = $_SESSION['login'];        //IF LOGGED IN SET TO SESSION VALUE
$un = $_SESSION['Username'];        //SET $UN TO USERNAME IN SESSION
}
```

Then I used javascript and php to alert the values which the variables contain:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("$un = <?php echo $un;?>");
</script>
```

With the login variable seemed to be no problem, since it had the good value, but the variable $un was wrong. When I wasn't logged in, it had no value, which is correct, but when I was logged in, it contained the value Admin, even when I wasn't logged in with Admin. In the browser options the cookie value seemed correct. I've checked the cookie on every page, and it worked just fine, just not on this page. What am I doing wrong that makes the browser(which is firefox by the way) think that it is always Admin that is logged in?

Comment: Why is this tagged `javascript`? It has nothing to do with JavaScript, it has to do with PHP and cookies.

Comment: I used javascript to alert the values...

Comment: That's irrelevant. I've removed the tag.

Comment: Your query can be used for sql injections: `"SELECT Password FROM accounts WHERE Username = '".$_POST['loginUn']."'");`

Comment: Obligatory link re Recode's comment: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: & you should not rely on cookie values, anybody can set those in his browser / script and pretend to be 'Admin'

Comment: @D-Inventor Are both scripts in the same directory?

Comment: Both scripts are in the same directory

Comment: From php manual: *If setcookie() successfully runs, it will return TRUE. This does not indicate whether the user accepted the cookie.*. Try looking your cookies and check if your is set as expected.

Comment: I see you're on a quest to develop the most hackable website ever.

Comment: Why aren't you using `$_SESSION` to track state?

Comment: In Firefox, erase all history and relogin as User, if the situation changes ?

Comment: It is not nice to say that it is the most hackable website ever. I'm just a beginner, and I've never heard of sessions before...

Comment: Okay I concede that wasn't helpful. To enumerate the specific vulnerabilities, you've hit the trifecta: no password hashing, blatant SQL injection, and storing user privileges in an editable cookie. Read http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php, and then http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php.

Comment: I've used sessions now, I escaped the inputs using mysqli_real_escape_string, and I encrypted the passwords using openssl_encrypt. Is it now safe enough?

Comment: And I have made a new phpmyadmin account with limited privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out what I did wrong. A piece of code which I found irrelevant, missed a = so the variable wasn't compared, but set to this wrong value.

Comment: You should still use `$_SESSION`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned earlier in the comments, there are many security risks in your script.

You should take a look at PHP's [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) to build your login. Using sessions, there will be only one cookie storing an ID and all the data will be stored on your server and can't be modified by the user.

Your problem with 'Admin' staying as cookie value could be a caching problem.

Comment: How could I solve this caching problem? I will take a look at this sessions, thanks.

Comment: Just did, but it doesn't solve the problem. The use of these sessions doesn't either.